c++ how to use types from class header in class without specifying class name
I have a class Person:
#include "Person.h"
class Person {
    public:
    coolType var;
    Person(coolType inp) {
        var = inp;
    }
}

And this is the header:
class Person {
    public:
    using coolType = long long;
    Person(coolType inp);
}

I want to use coolType in Person.cpp, but it won't let me without typing out Person::coolType every time. I can't do using namespace Person either. How can I use coolType in Person.cpp without typing out Person::coolType? Is this even a recommended way to define types?

Something like using pct = Person::coolType; (after the class definition) would do it.  I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it works.

Sidenote: your constructor should probably use a member initialization list. Person(coolType inp) : var(inp) { }

This is ODR violation. Refer to Same class name in different C++ files. Also see Separate classes into headers and source files in C++ that shows how to do this by puting the implementation of the class in header. Once you understand that, you'll be automatically able to see that you just need to put the second implementation that you showed in your post into the header.

What you have shown is not legal code, as you have conflicting definitions of the Person class type. This is a violation of the One Definition Rule.
The class should be defined one time, such as in Person.h, including the declarations of its members, eg:
#ifndef Person_H
#define Person_H

class Person {
public:
    using coolType = long long;
    coolType var;
    Person(coolType inp);
};

#endif

And then its member functions should be defined in Person.cpp, eg:
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(coolType inp) {
    var = inp;
}

Online Demo
Inside of the Person member functions, you can refer to coolType without having to prefix it with the Person:: class type, as shown above.
Unless you need to use coolType as a return type, when the compiler encounters the return type before seeing the class type in a member function definition, then you'll have to refer to it as Person::coolType, eg:
class Person {
public:
    using coolType = long long;
    ...
    coolType doSomething();
};

Person::coolType Person::doSomething()
{
    ...
}

In which case, you can use a trailing return type declaration so the class type is seen before the return type (see this answer), eg:
class Person {
public:
    using coolType = long long;
    ...
    auto doSomething() -> coolType;
};

auto Person::doSomething() -> coolType
{
    ...
}


Nitpick: The form class X { ... }; is a class definition; a class declaration would be class X;. The class definition seen here contains member function declarations, whose definitions are provided elsewhere.

@j6t i updated my answer. But technically, class X { ... }; is a declaration that includes a definition, but it is still a declaration nonetheless. class X; is also a declaration just without a definition (this is more commonly known as a forward-declaration). Similarly to how class member functions may be declared and defined at the same time within the class definition, or separately.
